# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException working with Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Validate.isTrue(true, "usage: supply url to fetch");
    try{
        String url="http://www.spoj.com/ranks/PRIME1/";
        Document doc= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements es=doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class","lightrow");
        System.out.println(es.get(0).child(0).text());


    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:26)
```

Please point me to my mistake and why am I getting it. I have followed this by an example from Jsoup official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is running as expected. I think that requires an argument to be passed to the program on the command line for it to run (an URL).

Please take a look at this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
```

Comment: Can you please tell the reason behind it, why argument count has to do with anything like that?

Comment: If you want to run that code, it does require an argument to be passed (which is the URL). The above statement validates if you have passed it.

Comment: Agreed. Ran your code with one commandlineargument and it worked (i get a timeout, but this is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155062/jsoup-times-out-xml-gets-white-space-error-basic-traversing-through-page-is-ti ). Make sure you add a argument to your program before you start it (even if you run from IDE).